# Angular Universal with AWS Lambda - TypeError

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, angular-universal

I'm currently struggling to get an Angular Universal app with SSR running with AWS Lambda.

I installed a new Angular app with

```
ng new my-angular-ssr-app
```

I added Angular Universal to my Angualr app

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject my-angular-ssr-app
```

I tested that my app works with npm and making a GET-Request (http://localhost:4000/) with Postman

```
npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr
```

I zipped the following folders and files with the required dependencies (aws-serverless-express)

```
- dist
- node_modules
- lambda.js
```

Uploaded the ZIP to a freshly created AWS Lambda function with a AWS API Gateway trigger

Made a GET-Request to the AWS API Gateway URL and got:

```
{
    "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

Cloudwatch logs the following for the GET-Request:

```
2019-10-10T07:17:17.935Z undefined ERROR Uncaught Exception
{
    "errorType": "TypeError",
    "errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'use' of undefined",
    "stack": [
        "TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:25:12)",
        "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)",
        "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)",
        "    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)",
        "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)",
        "    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)",
        "    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)",
        "    at _tryRequire (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:75:12)",
        "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:95:12)"
    ]
}
2019-10-10T07:17:17.963Z undefined INFO Node Express server listening on http://localhost:4000
```

My Lambda functions looks like this:

```
const awsServerlessExpress = require('aws-serverless-express');
const server = require('./dist/server');
const awsServerlessExpressMiddleware = require('aws-serverless-express/middleware');

const binaryMimeTypes = [
  'application/javascript',
  'application/json',
  'application/octet-stream',
  'application/xml',
  'application/x-font-ttf',
  'image/jpeg',
  'image/png',
  'image/gif',
  'text/comma-separated-values',
  'text/css',
  'text/html',
  'text/javascript',
  'text/plain',
  'text/text',
  'text/xml',
  'image/x-icon',
  'image/svg+xml'
];

server.app.use(awsServerlessExpressMiddleware.eventContext());

const serverProxy = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(server.app, null, binaryMimeTypes);

module.exports.handler = (event, context) => awsServerlessExpress.proxy(serverProxy, event, context);
```

I clearly did something wrong but I'm not sure what I'm missing. Has someone an idea what I have to change for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

In your `server.ts`, make sure you export the express app that is created. Without that export, there's no way for the lambda function to access that information from `./dist/server`.

The change should be as simple as throwing `export` in front of `const app = express()`. Make sure you rebuild the angular application before trying it out again.